# my car is running away, how can I do that the car could only go back and forth?

Tags: godot

the car should go in a straight line (blue arrow):

[image: how it should be]

My code is:

```
extends VehicleBody

const STEER_SPEED = 1.5
const STEER_LIMIT = 0.4

var steer_target = 0

export var engine_force_value = 40


func _physics_process(delta):
        var fwd_mps = transform.basis.xform_inv(linear_velocity).x
    
               if Input.is_action_pressed("accelerate"):
        
        # Increase engine force at low speeds to make the initial acceleration faster.
        var speed = linear_velocity.length()
        if speed < 5 and speed != 0:
            engine_force = clamp(engine_force_value * 5 / speed, 0, 100)
        else:
            engine_force = engine_force_value
    else:
        engine_force = 0
        
            if Input.is_action_pressed("reverse"):
                # Increase engine force at low speeds to make the initial acceleration faster.
                if fwd_mps >= -1:
                    var speed = linear_velocity.length()
                    if speed < 5 and speed != 0:
                        engine_force = -clamp(engine_force_value * 5 / speed, 0, 100)
                    else:
                        engine_force = -engine_force_value
                else:
                    brake = 1
            else:
                brake = 0.0
        
            steering = move_toward(steering, steer_target, STEER_SPEED * delta)
```

[image: example from godot]

Comment: Double check if it is correct. I remind you that indentation is important in GDScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the code would work as written.

However, to the point: if you want a `VehicleBody` to not turn left or right, you need to keep `steering = 0`.

Comment: when driving forward or backward, the car still runs away :((

Comment: if you specify transform.origin.x = 0 then the car just hangs in one place

Comment: @tormozzzz I don't know what is up with setting `transform.origin.x`, however `VehicleBody` is not intended to be manipulated like that, perhaps you are better off recreating it with `RigidBody` or `KinematicBody`. By the way, I have tried modifying the demo, and I believe `steering = 0` works as long as the terrain is flat and well aligned.

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/077956a0c96edb81f101b7cf031cf122 in the standard example, the car also turns off the road, when steering = 0